# Solr and search operators - lucene apache solr

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene

I got problem with search operator '*' (star)

My case is:

I search some doc field(it's dynamic field:

```
<fieldType name="bwcm_string" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <!-- <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/> -->
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" />
   </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
   <!-- <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/> -->
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

)

```
<dynamicField name="*_STRING"  type="b_string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

and I search using query '*\' and query filter by dynamic field with "*B*" and it return 
only doc where field contain 'B Bug', there are other docs with fields which contains A Bug and they also should be return in this case. 
Any advice ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite clear whether your query is `"*B*"` or `*B*` from your description, but I'm guessing the former.

In this case, your query is for the phrase `*B*`, that is, the asterisks are not being interpreted as query operators.  They are part of the term being searched for.  Since you are using `LowercaseTokenizer`, which is effectively a combination of `LetterTokenizer` and `LowercaseFilter` (by the way, following up a `LowercaseTokenizer` with a `LowercaseFilter` is redundant), any non-letter will be eliminated from the query, meaning your effective query is for simply: `B`

Instead, just search for `*B*`.  You may need to `setAllowLeadingWildcard(true)` on the query parser.  Given the cases provided, though, just `B*` would be quite adequate (and will perform much better).

Comment: I change definition of this field, as You can see up - now I got problem with search only fo fields which start of B* and this not working

Comment: Well, why did you change it to use a `KeywordTokenizer`?

Comment: I change this because indexed fields values were splitted, and using this tokenizer make the value just a big string. In previous presentation was a mistake. After solr reindex, search operator * on first sight works correctly. I will test this later.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you need is [ReversedWildcardFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory).

Looks like your exact use case is described here: [Wildcard queries and how Solr handles them](http://solr.pl/en/2010/12/20/wildcard-queries-and-how-solr-handles-them/)

Comment: I change definition of this field, as You can see up - now I got problem with search only fo fields which start of B* and this not working

Comment: You're using KeywordTokenizerFactory, is there a reason for it? With current setup for "A Bug" you will get following tokens: "gub a", "a bug". With StandardTokenizerFactory you will get: "a", "bug", "gub" and query for "*B*" should work :) Try using "http://hostname:8983/solr/#/core_name/analysis" to predict how field will bahave

Comment: Mmmm why do You think that I get token like "bug a" from "a bug" - this are two different tokens -- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-KeywordTokenizer any way, on first sight, now it's works correctly, I will keep testing

Comment: I mentioned that of indexing "A Bug" gives you: "gub a", "a bug" (assuming you'll use filter I mentioned). I would not use KeywordTokenizerFactory as it's good for EXACT matches, not for fuzzy matches of any kind

Comment: Thanks, for replies. For me this is enough